# Postgres setup for multiple projects

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, database-projects

I have a Postgres db server setup on my raspberry pi.  With this I am working on two distinct projects:

- Project1
- Project2

For these projects I have different users and the users of each should not be able to see the data of the other project.  What i did to enable this was create two databases on the server:

- project1_db
- project2_db

So my setup on pgadmin4 looks like:

=> Servers

=====> Projects

==========>project1_db

==========>project2_db

I also created two users:

- project1_user
- project2_user

I made each of these users the owners of their respective db.  By doing this i expected when logged in as project1_user to not be able to see project2_db info (basically be told when clicking the db in pgadmin4 that i dont have permissions).  However, I was still able to click in and then dig into schema/public/tables.  I noticed when looking at privileges for the db in pgAdmin4 that PUBLIC kept being added even after I deleted it - and my understanding is that this makes it viewable by all.

So my questions are:

1. Is this server/db setup appropriate for what im trying to achieve? If it is, why am i not getting expected privileges?
2. Is my user setup appropriate / what is the correct user roles setup to use to achieve my goal?  And how does the PUBLIC role tie into this?
3. Am I missing something obvious / or do i have misunderstanding of the tools?

UPDATE: I just found this [PostgreSQL - Who or what is the "PUBLIC" role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108975/postgresql-who-or-what-is-the-public-role) on the public role. Which i guess answers the question on public.

I also realized that after I was making updates I was only refreshing my databases not the whole server so the changes werent being pushed down. After I removed public access and refreshed the server the permissions worked as expected.  I am now getting my expected behavior.